# App takes 130 ms to load the main page content, should I try asynchronus loading

Tags: loading

My desktop application comes with some examples it can show on the main home page. The trouble is, those examples take ~120ms to load, which if done synchronously effectively delays application startup time.

An alternative is to load the examples after the application has loaded, but that means the interface is not 'static' because as soon as it loads, the small table with examples 'appears' and this could be jarring.

What is the best experience UX wise to go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nielsen-Norman Research Group, a leader in UX research, have identified some fairly consistent effects of various wait times.

> **0.1 seconds** gives the feeling of **instantaneous** response...
> **1 second** keeps the user's flow of thought **seamless**...
> **10 seconds** keeps the user's **attention**...
> <sub>From https://www.nngroup.com/articles/website-response-times/</sub>

You say the examples add an additional 120-130ms to load, but that's still not a hugely significant amount of time. The difference will probably not even be noticeable. What might be noticeable is the page moving after initial load. Human vision is highly sensitive to movement, so minimizing that might provide a smoother experience while still only adding a negligible amount of additional wait time.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Agree, the page moving is *very* annoying after a small delay, especially when you're trying to click something and it moves from underneath you (even worse: it moves something else clickable underneath your mouse/finger). If you do have to do that see if its possible to reserve space on the initial layout so jumps don't happen.